# Show Image from application cache in phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap

I am developing an app with phonegap. Using camera and file, I am able to capture and store image at application cache directory (Android/data/com.myapp.package/cache). Now the real problem is, I am unable to display image at my app.
Here is my html -

```
<img id="project_img" src="" />
```

I tried following code -

```
function getImage(imgUri) { // My Image name without extension
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.cacheDirectory, function success(dirEntry) {

        // JPEG file
        var imgname = imgUri+'.jpg';
        dirEntry.getFile(imgname, { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {
            alert("got file: " + fileEntry.toURL()); /* Produce file:///data/user/0/com.myapp.package/cache/1.jpg.*/
            alert("got file: " + fileEntry.toInternalURL());
            var image1 = document.getElementById('project_img');
            image1.src = fileEntry.toURL();

        }, function(err){alert('Error creating file'+JSON.stringify(err));});

    }, function(errr){alert('Error reslove uri'+JSON.stringify(errr));});
}
```

I got no error. But no image is shown. I have tried `image1.src = fileEntry.toInternalURL();` but none of them work. Any help will be appreciated.